# Boundary of a $k-$Cell Definition

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

In the book I am reading, the **Boundary** of a $(k+1)-$cell $\varphi$ is defined to be the $k-$chain

> $$\partial\varphi=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{j+1}(\varphi\circ \iota^{j,1}-\varphi\circ \iota^{j,0}) $$

Where
$$ \iota^{j,0}:(u_1,\ldots,u_k)\mapsto(u_1,\ldots,u_{j-1},0,u_j,\ldots,u_k)$$
$$ \iota^{j,1}:(u_1,\ldots,u_k)\mapsto(u_1,\ldots,u_{j-1},1,u_j,\ldots,u_k)$$
I am struggling to reconcile this with the intuitive definition of the boundary of a region. Also, I am uncertain as to why there is an alternating negative/positive sign attached to this sum.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** Here a cell denotes a smooth map from $I^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, rather than the image of the smooth map. Apparently it can mean one or the other in different cases.

Comment: So the $(-1)^{j+1}$ provides consistent orientations for all of the faces. The maps $\varphi\circ i^{j,1},\varphi\circ i^{j,0}$ you can think of as two opposite faces of your figure, and the minus sign just provides the fact that if one face is turning clockwise the other one is turning counter clockwise. I suggest you use these things and examine some basic figures such as the identity map on $I^2$ and $I^3$. That should provide you sufficient intuition for the generalization.